# $P(A \cap B) = P(A | B) . P(B)$ Can we prove it with the existing three axioms of Probability for any case?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I started reading conditional probability . I found the following equation. I can not understand the equation. $P(A \cap B) = P(A | B) . P(B)$ .Can we prove it for any case? $P(X)$ denotes the probability of happening $X$.

According to the Kolmogrov's definition ,  $\frac { P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$  is denoted by the notation $P(A|B)$. If this is so , then how $\frac { P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ gives the probability of happening $A$ , when $B$ has happened already.

I do not think it can be proved except for the case when the random experiment is done on a sample space with finite number of points.

I think we have to take this statement as an Axiom. Can anyone please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: How do you define $p(A|B)$?

Comment: What is the _definition_ of $p(A|B)$ here?

Comment: This is not an  axiom. It is a   definition. The equation defined $p(A|B)$.

Comment: It is simply the definition of [Conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition) (followed by an algebraic manipulation).

Comment: I know the definition of $P(A|B)$ is if the event $B$ happens then the probability of happening $A$ is $P(A|B)$..How do you deduce from here that $P(A|B)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$..@RobertIsrael

Comment: I know the definition of $P(A|B)$ is if the event $B$ happens then the probability of happening $A$ is $P(A|B)$..How do you deduce from here that $P(A|B)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$..@DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Have you seen the next para in your link namely ' as an axiom of probability' ?@MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: According to kolmogrov's definition $P(A|B) $ is just a notation of the term $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ ..Can you explain how this term $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ denotes the probability of happening $A$ when $B$ has happened already..@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @José Carlos Santos  can you please reopen the question? I have edited the question..

Comment: @cmi Think of a Venn diagram for A and B. Knowing that B happened, you are in the B circle and the question is: given that (you are in B), what is the chance that you are also in A? In other words, P(A|B) is the portion of B which happens to also lie in A, i.e. P(A and B) / P(B).